# C# Getting values from sublist on the basis of data matched in the list

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a situation where I have a list which contains another list and there is a string which is matched on both levels and returns only the matched values from both the lists.

For example:
Category : "A" contains products "A", "B" and "AA"
Category : "B" contains products "BA", "C" and "D"
Cateogry : "" contains products "A", "B"

If my input parameter is let's say A, the result should be :
Category "A" with products "A" and "AA"
Category "" with products "A"

If my input is B, the result should be:
Category "B" with products "BA"
Category "" with products "B"

What I have done so Far is:

```
 result = AllCustomListValues.
                         Where(c => c.CategoryName.ToLower().Contains(searchTextInput.ToLower())
                         || c.CategoryName == ""
                         ).ToList();

            foreach (var value in result)
            {
                if (value.CategoryName == "")
                {
                    foreach (var CustomList in value.CustomLists)
                    {
                        if (!CustomList.ListName.ToLower().Contains(searchTextInput.ToLower()))
                            CustomListToRemove.Add(CustomList);
                    }
                    foreach (var ListToRemove in CustomListToRemove)
                        value.CustomLists.Remove(ListToRemove);
                }
            }
```

Here, AllCustomListValues contains the whole data i.e list which contains the sublist(Category list which Contains Custom List). I am matching the input text string at the category level and then getting the first set of matching categories, in the second level I'm trying to get the custom list data which do not match with the input text string and add then remove that from the main category list's sublist i.e. Custom list, this all is working fine but seems to be very exhaustive and rigid, I am looking for an easier and flexible option.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Of course. Which platform would you like? WinForms, WPF, UMP? Do you have any code to start with?

Comment: I am working with .net MVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't sure why you do `if (value.CategoryName == "")` on your second level so i skipped it (feel free to add back).
I also believe by deleting sub-items you are mutating your `AllCustomListValues` variable which might not be desirable.

You could potentially try something along these lines:

```
searchTextInput = searchTextInput.ToLower(); // just so we only do it once.
AllCustomListValues.SelectMany(cat => cat.CustomLists, (cat, product) => new { cat.CategoryName, product.ListName, product}) // basically we flatten the Product structure and expose properties to search and rebuild our list later 
.Where(c => c.CategoryName.ToLower().Contains(searchTextInput) || c.CategoryName == "" || c.ListName.ToLower().Contains(searchTextInput)) // apply your filters here to both Category and Filter
.GroupBy(i => i.CategoryName) // reconstructing your hierarchy
.Select(g => new Category {CategoryName = g.Key, CustomLists = g.Select(p => p.product).ToList() } )
.ToList();
```